# Help with volume integration application problem using Disk or Washer Methods, revolving about x-axis, revolving about y-axis.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, applications, transcendental-functions

I need to find the volumes of the solids generated by revolving the regions bounded by the graphs of the equations about the given lines: y = $\sqrt {x}$ $y=0$, and $x=3$. A) the $x-axis$ B) the $y-axis$ C) the line $x=3$ D) the line $x=9$. I've already solved part A using the Disk method, and I got $\frac92$$\pi$, which was correct, but I'm confused as to what upper bound I should be using to solve part B, and I have no idea how to start C and D.

Comment: Not an answer, but it irritates me that this topic remains on AP calculus courses. It's confusing, unnecessarily difficult, and practically useless. It's pure calculation and does nothing to enhance the understanding of the course material.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you revolve the region bound by $y = 0, x = 3, y = \sqrt x \,$, we get a paraboloid and you have already found the volume correctly.

Now for part $(b),$ when you revolve it around $Y$axis, you get horizontal circular discs stacked up starting at $y = 0$ with radius increasing as $|y|$ increases. The radius is given by

$x = y^2$ (as it is bound by curve $y = \sqrt x$)

As the outer bound of $x$ is $x = 3$, upper bound of $y = \sqrt x = \sqrt 3$. Also the lower bound as given in the question, $y = 0$.

So the desired volume $ \displaystyle V_b = \int_0^{\sqrt 3} \pi x^2 dy = \int_0^{\sqrt 3} \pi y^4 dy = \frac{9\sqrt 3 \, \pi}{5}$

Now for part $(c)$, the horizontal circular radius is

$r = 3 - x = 3 - y^2; r = 3$ when $y = 0, r = 0$ when $y = \sqrt 3$

So the desired volume $ \displaystyle V_c = \pi \int_0^{\sqrt 3} (3-y^2)^2 dy$

The same applies for part $(d)$ but the radius will be $(9 - y^2)$ and bounds will be $\sqrt 3 \le y \le 3 \, (x = 3, x = 9)$.